# How to do string comparison with wildcard pattern in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Did C# provide any method to compare the string with a
wildcard pattern like. Or I can say I want to find a "Like Operator" to do string comparison.
Suppose I have a string .I also have a paragraph , I want to find the string on this parapgraph,But how.In SQL we can do it just using the **LIKE** operator.

**Any Suggestion  and reply is grateful.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [System.StringComparer that supports wildcard (*) ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433998/system-stringcomparer-that-supports-wildcard)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Wildcards are a complicated beast (a form of regular expressions), but it sounds like you want the `Contains` method. You can just do `paragraph.Contains(sentence)`.

Answer (score 7):

[`String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1wwdcbf.aspx) has a [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) method that should suffice, returns a `boolean`

```
"Big string that represents a paragraph".Contains("that");
```

Example from the [Contains Method MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx):

```
// This example demonstrates the String.Contains() method
using System;

class Sample 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
    string s1 = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    string s2 = "fox";
    bool b;
    b = s1.Contains(s2);
    Console.WriteLine("Is the string, s2, in the string, s1?: {0}", b);
    }
}
/*
This example produces the following results:

Is the string, s2, in the string, s1?: True
*/
```

If you need more advanced matching then Regex might be the correct route, but from the example you stated I think contains will work fine.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Regex to define wildcards. These don't work exactly like the DOS ones, but are more powerful.
See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228595(VS.80).aspx